# API key encryption for Github?

Tags: python, api, github

I'm writing a Python application that utilizes the Tumblr API and was wondering how I would go about hiding, or encrypting, the API key.

Github warns against pushing this information to a repo, so how would I make the application available to the public and still follow that policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to post your API key? Why not post your app code to Github without your API key and have a configuration parameter for your users to add their own API key?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the concepts behind deployment too well, but what if I wanted to distribute my application so that users could install it using `pip install application`? Would users still need to add their own API key?

Comment: When someone installs your application, you can include a configuration file, e.g. `config.yml`, that has a place for a user to add their API key. This would be the same as someone downloading an app and adding their own configuration parameters. For example, installing WordPress provides a `wp-config.php` file where people add their own database credentials (username / password).

Comment: To get an API key from Tumblr requires you to register an application, so it seems a little backwards to me that someone has to register another application to retrieve an API key to then use for my application.